# How do I use proxy authentication with an SSL connection using HttpsUrlConnection?

Tags: java, http, ssl, proxy

I am trying to connect to a web site that uses SSL. This connection is via proxy (squid) that also requires proxy authentication.

I am currently using HttpsUrlConnection for connections within my app and would prefer to continue to use this if it is possible.

The problem occurs when you make the connection using connection.open("https://domain.com"), the HTTP CONNECT is sent immediately before you have had a chance to set any headers including "Proxy-Authentication", in a normal http connection nothing is sent until getOutputStream is called, so just setting this header works.

It is possible to set a defaultAuthenticator for this that returns the correct name and password. There are two problems with this though:

1. The application is a web application running inside a web server with unknown other applications. If I set a default authenticator, would this effect other applications? (for the same reason setting system properties is out)
2. I also need the ability to use different proxies in different connections. e.g. I may have a connection that goes to proxy1.domain.com and another that goes to proxy2.domain.com, each with different credentials.

What is the correct way of achieving this? I would be very surprised if this was not possible for HttpUrlConnection given its widespread use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not totally mistaken this cannot be achieved using the JVM `URLConnection` and friends. Besides, given its track record in terms of severe bugs and memory leaks it has been on our corporate black list for quite some time.

Use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html).

As for your question 1, *in general* each `ClassLoader` has its own copy of a class and the classes static members. Since, `Authenticator` is a JVM class I assume it's loaded by (one of) the parent `ClassLoader`s of your application `ClassLoader` which assures there's only a single copy of the `Authenticator` *class* inside the JVM.

Comment: This is the method we we ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

You set a `java.net.Authenticator`.